# Blank table view when trying to populate the cells from an object array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This function successfully gets the room values from Firebase and sets them to `var usersRooms: [Room] = []`:

```
            userRoomRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (roomSnap) in

                for eachRoom in roomSnap.value as! [String : AnyObject] {
                    let roomID = eachRoom.key as! String
                    userRoomRef.child(roomID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (roomSnap) in

                        if let roomInfo = roomSnap.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

                            guard let roomName = roomInfo["roomName"] as! String! else {print("Error getting room name"); return}
                            guard let participants = roomInfo["participants"] as! [String]! else {print("Error getting room participants"); return}
                            print("\n\nRoom Name: \(roomName)\nRoom Participants: \(participants)\nRoom ID: \(roomID)\n")

                            self.usersRooms.append(Room(id: roomID, name: roomName, participants: participants)) // This array gets updated
                            self.currentUser?.rooms.append(Room(id: roomID, name: roomName, participants: participants))// This doesn't. Why?

                            print("\n\nUser's Rooms: \(self.usersRooms)\n\n")
                            print("\n\nRooms (from currentUser): \(self.currentUser?.rooms)\n\n")
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
```

Prints:

```
Room Name: Room One
Room Participants: ["tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53"]
Room ID: -KhNIakMWNn1aKegRMZu

Room Name: Room Three
Room Participants: ["tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53"]
Room ID: -KhShqdKkOsfEsi_q7pE

Room Name: Room Two
Room Participants: ["tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53"]
Room ID: -KhNItkG77w0lLBo4Y0A
```

And printing `usersRooms` shows me:

```
User's Rooms: [*app name*.Room, *app name*.Room, *app name*.Room]
```

However when I try to populate my table view using

```
cell.textLabel?.text = usersRooms[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].name
```

It comes up blank. Am I missing a step? It appears that the rooms are inserted into the array, and I also have the other table view methods using `usersRooms`. What am I missing here?

Comment: The duplicate is about a collection view but it's the same basic issue. You need to reload the table view at the end of the completion block.

Comment: Oh dear that makes perfect sense. Apologies for the duplicate, do you want to post an answer or should I delete?

Comment: That was indeed the issue by the way, if it wasn't clear, it's fixed now.

Comment: There's no need to post an answer. Leave the duplicate. It may help others in the future to find the solution.

Comment: Sure thing - thanks!